# Объясните поведение defer в GO

Tags: golang

Насколько я понимаю - использование `defer FUNC()` внутри блока кода/функции гарантирует вызов `FUNC()` в любом случае при завершение работы этого блока/функции.

Как тогда объяснить поведение `defer` в этом фрагменте ([Живой пример](https://play.golang.org/p/FPA0wrRyw1f)):

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "errors"
)
func test() error {
  err := errors.New("some error")
  return err
}
func main() {
  if err := test(); err!=nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR EXIT")
    return
  }
  defer fmt.Println("DEFER EXIT")
  fmt.Println("NORMAL EXIT")
}
```

Я ожидаю увидеть:

```
ERROR EXIT
DEFER EXIT
```

А получаю только:

```
ERROR EXIT
```

Что именно я упускаю?

Comment: Всё просто - `defer` - это отложенный вызов. Если вызов не отложен, то вызова нет. Ну и выполняются они в обратном порядке - снизу вверх, типа.

Answer (score 3):

defer надо писать ДО того места где возможна ошибка. Они выполняются по принципу LIFO.

```
func main() {
  defer fmt.Println("DEFER EXIT")
  fmt.Println("SOME STAFF")
  defer fmt.Println("DEFER EXIT2")
  if err := test(); err!=nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR EXIT")
    return
  }
  fmt.Println("NORMAL EXIT")
}
```

Вывод будет:

```
SOME STAFF
ERROR EXIT
DEFER EXIT2
DEFER EXIT
```

Comment: Как быть в таком случае:
`resp, err := http.Get(URL)
if err != nil {
log.Println(err.Error())
return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
}`
?

Comment: @Борис в этом случае если вернулась ошибка то resp.Body нет, соответственно и закрывать ничего не надо